# pbuilder create fail

Tags: ubuntu, build, debian

I'm attempting to run "sudo pbuilder create" however, when retrieving packages a different one always seems to time out and fail causing the whole process. I've skimmed the man page, and I can't find any flags to set pbuilder such that it would retry several times to retrieve a failed package. Is this possible or do I have to just keep running "sudo pbuilder create" and hope for the best to get my build environment working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of an option to override this.  A brute-force approach I have used in the past in order to build my packages is to untar the file base.tgz, chroot into it and then remove the apt caches by hand. I would then update, re-tar the base.tgz file.  Not elegant, but it worked.

Comment: Not pretty, but I'm up and running!

Answer (score 1):

You can create ~/.pbuilderrc and indicate different debian mirror for distribution.

Check [config example](http://www.tolaris.com/2009/03/31/backporting-debian-packages-with-pbuilder/).